# Searching Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

I have two dataframes:

**df_1**

Contains: Ticket_ID and Email_Address

**df_2**

Contains: Email_Address and MachineID

I need to search df_2 using the email addresses in df_1 and if there is a match, write the MachineID to a new column in df_1.

I can do one off queries using DataFrame.query but I'm not sure how to pass the list of email addresses from df_1.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some **verifiable**: meaning some small inputs to generate a small `df_1` and `df_2` and show us how you would do the query that mentioned you can do; **complete**: show what you expect the final table to look like; **example**. If you provide all these it's likely someone will provide some reasonable answer without having to think about how **you** implemented your dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print df_1
   Ticket_ID Email_Address
0        100   joe@aaa.com
1        200    koe@aaa.sk

print df_2
  Email_Address  MachineID
0   joe@aaa.com          9
1  joe1@aaa.com          2
2  joe2@aaa.com          3

print pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['Email_Address'], how='left')
   Ticket_ID Email_Address  MachineID
0        100   joe@aaa.com          9
1        200    koe@aaa.sk        NaN
```

Comment: I totally agree. Then you can use get output dataframe where you can use `query` afterward e.g. `df.query("'Email_Address' == 'joe@aaa.com'")`